# Redux Vs BehaviourSubject - whats the difference?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs

Assuming you're an Angular dev you might have a service called User Service. This service has a behaviour subject (see rxjs) which your components subscribe to and lets say the service also has a few methods to change the user state.

your top level component listens to the user service state and inputs it to it's child component. That child component then calls a method on the service to change the user state and the behaviour subject emits a new value. Now your component listening gets an updated value and passes this down to its children.

Or in another implementation you have a bunch of components at the same level listening for state change. One calls a services method to change state and the state is emitted, all components listening get the new state.

Over on the Redux side I am very new but I understand that there is one state area. your components instead write to the state and listen to the state from there.

I dont see the difference? I know Redux also allows you to see what actions where actually called to change the state, whereas in the behaviour subject example they are completely decoupled and have no concept of why or how the state was changed - they just know what the state is now.

Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: I don't understand the down votes you've been given. I'd like to know advantages of using Redux instead of rxJS' BehaviourSubject observable.. I just found this article that I intend to read- and I may follow back up with a simplified answer: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/

Comment: I get downvotes because this is stackoverflow and if you ask a general question without specific code you dont get an answer.

If you do post back Id be very interested to see what you say. Still.

Comment: I was thinking more about your question this morning, and I think the only thing you could have improved is just asking: what are the advantages/disadvantages of one over the other. They're obviously different, hell, even if someone comments "they have different names" their answer would technically be right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have since realised that the intent is different. Using a behaviour subject is fine - the intent is to store some state and you might have the same state, or some amount of cross-over state, stored in many behaviour subjects across your app (you shouldnt but it might be valid).

The intent of redux is different. It offers an approach with a single source of truth as state is stored and mutated in only 1 place in the entire application. Data is also immutable. Because of these 2 factors it is possible to establish a robust consistent timeline regarding your data mutations as well as what events from what area of the system caused those mutations, and that has allowed clever people to write clever tools to debug your application by 'rewinding time'.

The other answers here are great but I feel that they deal with implementation details, like actions (obvious) and reducers (mutation functions) and the real takeaway is the the difference is subtle since it lies in the difference in intent between the flux pattern and the observer pattern.

The flux pattern is as described - data stores that you can observe on in an immutable single truth way. I believe you could say it is a compound pattern using the state pattern and the observer pattern.

The observer pattern is about decoupling code through listening for events - probably the same events - and running different areas of code with different single responsibilities to ensure decoupling. eg a user changes their username on a forum via a popup, all the posts they have made on the open page should update with their new name, and the username displayed in the top right of the website header should change. These are different areas of responsibility.

Answer (score 22):

I've encountered this question when I came across a very common use case: developing a loader/spinner that can be toggled from anywhere in my app.

I myself have raised a similar question: what exactly are the benefits of redux, especially when behavior subject handles my current need.

I recommend this article:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/

The article mentions key times when a store should be used, and some benefits:

- When injecting up the component tree into components where it seems naturally out of scope. (using behaviorsubject avoids injection like this anyway)
- Performance, testability, tooling, predictability

It also mentions negatives of using a store like Redux:

- The store does solve the problem of component interaction, but it also creates the need for managing state in your application, which might otherwise not exist when using other solutions.

After watching all the videos, and reading all the words, I've decided Redux is great. I really want to use it. However, for my current use case of sharing the state of a single object holding only:

```
{ show: true }
```

or

```
{ show: false }
```

It clearly is not the correct choice to adopt an entire library to handle only this single state when rxjs/behaviorsubject does exactly what I need with very little overhead.

The phrase that really struck me in the article:

**If you don't know whether you need Redux or not, you don't need Redux.**

I think that is to say, Redux is here to solve a huge problem: data immutability across large data stores. If you don't have that problem... Redux is not needed by you yet. :)

Answer (score 10):

I have an **Angular application** implemented using **behavior subjects in a global service** for **preserving and updating state** which i observe for changes throughout my application.

**The code is very legible, works perfectly without issue, accomplishes the goal and is easy to troubleshoot.**

With that said, I took the time to try and migrate to a **redux/flux pattern**  with **ngrx** and *while i get the concept and benefit of having a central and immutable store for state*, it felt like i was creating a *tremendous level of complexity* throughout my application in-order to implement it properly and have since abandoned the library.

It was the need for having to integrate *side effects* with **ngrx effects** that really made it frustrating to work with. The code did not *feel* reliable and i was beginning to run into problems whereas multiple observable subscriptions began to crop up during runtime, not to mention, a whole assortment of other issues related to observing for changes, legibility and organization of my code.

At the end of the day, **is the best not the enemy of the good?**

Answer (score 6):

Redux is an implementation of the Flux pattern. That means that the actions and reducers are a parts of the pattern as well as having a single source of truth providing immutable state. Using a service that provides a piece of immutable state is just a part of what redux (or other libs using the Flux pattern like ngRx) provide.

Something to note is that ngRx (a lib similar to redux made around observables for angular) uses BehaviorSubjects for the state (or store in ngRx terms). So using the BehaviorSubject is definitely part of it!

Something to note when using Subjects is to try to make them private and allow components to subscribe to them through a method returning the asObservable function on the Observable. It can save you from some headaches later :)

Comment: You highlight some good stuff, but- actually, I think it might be incorrect to say Redux is an implementation of the Flux pattern (I recommend an edit on this point). From the article in my answer:

It's important to be aware that Redux does not protect against the chained dispatch scenario mentioned in the original talks of Flux. With Redux we can trigger another dispatch from the subscribe method while in original Flux if an action was already being dispatched we could not trigger another.

So it seems to me that it is not designed with the main principle of the Flux pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I have combined BehaviorSubject with redux,
you suppose to use it as a regular observable 
and when you set new value the library clone the value to new value and dispatch automatic action, so you can debug it with redux-devtools-extension.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-behavior-subject